# Client authentication with RubyLDAP ldap

Tags: ruby, ldap, ssl, openldap

I'm trying to implement a feature that uses LDAP over SSL (SSL, not TLS), it needs to connect to a SSL-enabled LDAP server (i.e OpenLDAP), bind and then do any additional queries. It also needs to support client-authentication, and this is where things get tricky: The client is a web application written in Ruby, and we are using RubyLDAP (so far we have used it for non-SSL ldap stuff with great success).

My question is: Is there a way to load a client certificate and send its data over the wire to the LDAP server when doing a LDAP::SSLConn? I haven't found anything obvious on the API docs (http://ruby-ldap.sourceforge.net/rdoc/) nor while googling around.

I know I that I can prevent the server from asking for a certificate by putting the following on slapd.conf (OpenLDAP):

```
TLSVerifyClient never
```

However, this is not an option here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant.
Do you need a client cert?  You can also use bind users and [acl's](https://openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html) in openldap.  This would be much easier and manageable from within your openldap server than client cert's.

To enable the client side ssl you need to point ruby-ldap to the correct CA cert, the one that singed your servers cert.  on your client, in the `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`

```
TLS_CACERT /etc/ssl/yourldapsca.pem
```